# C Hexadecimal Addition Incorrect Output

Tags: c, hex

I've got this function that adds two hexadecimal numbers together one byte at a time by acessing the number stored in each object. However this sometimes results in the incorrect output, which I believe is due to an error with the carry value.

```
IntStatus_t intN_add(IntN_t opa, IntN_t opb, IntN_t* result)
{
    uint8_t i = NBYTES;
    uint8_t carry = 0;
    uint16_t sum = 0;

    do {
        i--;
        sum = opa.data[i] + opb.data[i] + carry;
        if (sum > 255) {
            result->data[i] = sum;
            carry = (sum - 255);        
        } else {
            result->data[i] = sum;
            carry = 0;
        }
        
    } while (i > 0);
```

For example,

```
Provide an intN number in hex encoded form: 00 80 ff
Provide an intN number in hex encoded form: 01 80 01


The sum is:0x030100
```

Returns 0x030100 instead of 0x20100.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is to get rid of the custom integer types and switch to `stdint.h` everywhere. We can't really answer if there's an overflow or such without knowing the _actual_ type of these variables - if there is integer promotion or not etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong:

```cpp
carry = (sum - 255);
```

If you add `200` and `200`, you'll get `400`, which *should* be `400 - 256  = 144` with a carry of `1`. However, your carry calculation would give you a number in the hundreds, which is clearly *not* what you want.

Taking that into account would give you something like:

```cpp
sum = opa.data[i] + opb.data[i] + carry;
result->data[i] = sum % 256;
carry = sum / 256;
/*
if (sum > 255) {
    result->data[i] = sum - 256;
    carry = 1;
} else {
    result->data[i] = sum;
    carry = 0;
}
*/
```

You'll notice there I've replaced the `if` statement with a shorter snippet. The correct `if`-based solution is given in the comment that follows it, but the shorter form will give you the same result with less code, and also work if you expand your code to handle more than two input numbers at once<sup>(1)</sup>.

What's happening with your *given* example and code, `0x0080ff + 0x018001`, is:

- Add `0xff` and `0x01`, with carry `0`: `255 + 1 + 1 = 256` which gives you `0` and a carry of `1`. That's the *correct* value and carry but more by accident than anything else :-)
- Add `0x80` and `0x80`, with carry `1`: `128 + 128 + 1 = 257` which gives you `1` and a carry of `2`.
- Add `0x00` and `0x01`, with carry `2`: `0 + 1 + 2 = 3` which gives you `3` and a carry of `0`.
- Hence final result is `0x030100`, rather than the correct `0x020100`.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Adding two "digits" with a valid carry can never give you more than `255 + 255 + 1 = 511`, so the highest carry you can get from that would be `1`. However, adding three numbers digit-wise could see `255 + 255 + 255 + 1 = 765`, which would be `253` with carry `2`.

Comment: `(uint16_t)(opa.data[i]) ` What does this cast achieve? We know nothing about the types of the original integers and this cast is only meaningful in a system with 16 bit integer. On a 32 bit system, integer promotion will happen. You'd turn one operand unsigned even if it was negative but left the other as it was. Then everything gets promoted to `int` if it wasn't already `int` or larger.

Comment: @Lundin, the fact that the code is using `uint8/16_t` would *suggest* each digit is actually of the former type. But you're correct that there's no proof that this is the case (and also on the promotion of lesser-ranked integers to `int`) so I'll adjust the answer.